# issues with 'this' when using within jquery code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, dom

I want to use values of the calling object within the jquery code block, but 'this' is mapped to the jquery object and not eh caller! How to solve this PLEASE?

```
// class
myClass = function (){
    // member object
    this._localVars = {
        _elementClass:'.elem-class',
        _dots:null,
        _dotStatus:null
    };

    // member function
    this.func1 = function() {
        $(this._elementClass).each(function(_index, _element){
            // this._localVars._dots[_index] = _element; ... this line throws an error 'this._localVars' is undefined ... as 'this' is html element here and not an object of the calling class
        });
    };
};
```

Please suggest how can I use the 'this' inside the jquery code block to refer the variables/objects of the class and not HTML/jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `jQuery.proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) to set the value of `this` that you want.

You pass your function as the first parameter, and the current `this` as the second.

```
myClass = function (){
    this._localVars = {
        _elementClass:'.elem-class',
        _dots:[],
        _dotStatus:null
    };
    this.func1 = function() {
        $(this._localVars._elementClass).each( $.proxy(function(_index, _element) {
             this._localVars._dots[_index] = _element;
        }, this));
    };
};

var cl = new myClass();

cl.func1();

console.log(cl._localVars._dots);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try saving `this` object into a local variable

```
    var myObject = this;
    $(this._elementClass).each(function(_index, _element){
        myObject._localVars._dots[_index] = _element;
    });
```

Comment: I will give that a shot, however if I go with 'var myObject = this;' won't it create a local copy of the object and then whatever manipulation I do, will effect that local copy and not the global collection?

Comment: @Mandeep No, it will just create a reference to the old object. It's not C.